# mysql regular expression search is not working

Tags: mysql, regex

I am trying to execute this, but its throwing the error. Can anyone please help?

```
 SELECT * FROM `country` WHERE name regex '^ab$';
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'regex '^ab$' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

- My motto is to get "**united states of america**" record while user
  searches for any phrase like

  united states of/united states/states united/america united/america states

Can anyone please tell me how I can write a regular expression for this requirement.

```
 SELECT * FROM `country` WHERE name regex '^united states$';
```

But `Like` is working fine with

```
SELECT * FROM `country` WHERE name like '%ab%';
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: try `rlike` in place of `regex`

Comment: thanks jan..i'll try this..but my requirement is much more can u read my post again pls

Comment: so, you want us to write you a regex AND fix your SQL syntax? ;-)

Comment: For the first half, specify what should match and what shouldn't.

Comment: Alternatively, just use MySQL's built-in fuzzy fulltext search

Comment: actually both..but someone edited my post..as a start im just trying with '^ab$' but it is throwing the error..

Comment: Incorrect regex will not throw a syntax error. It either matches or doesn't. The correct SQL syntax, however, is `name rlike 'ab'`

Comment: thanks for ur reply. but rlike is not working either jan  :( throwing same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to what sp00m has noted, fairly sure your regex isn't what you are looking for.  `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of line, respectively, so using these regexes:

```
^ab$
^united states$
```

is effectively looking for an exact match on "ab" and "united states".  If you are looking for a query equivalent to `like '%ab%'`, remove the beginning and end of line characters, your regex simply being:

```
ab
```

I do wonder what was wrong with using a `LIKE '%ab%'` though.  Seems like the more typical method.

Neither option, however, will make the regex `united states` or `^united states$` or using a like similarly match "america united" though

Comment: Thanks friend. :) its working femto Rgon.. but i'm wondering does it work for all the phrase like united states of/united states/states united/america united/america states ??                                                           I'm checking it out..

Comment: As noted, no.  I don't know what to make of that requirement.  Would it be acceptable to match both "america united" and "united kingdom" and "united Arab Emirates" against `united states`?

Comment: it is working fine with united/united states/united states of america. But its not working for other phrases like states united/america united/america states..how can write regular expression for this...

Comment: s femtoRgon. i need to get all the records if some part/parts are  matched with it. because it is autocomplete field user may search for any part or some parts of the name

Comment: if you need it to see `united states` and magically know that "america" is a related term, you can't.  If it's acceptable to match the cases I listed above, then something like `(united.*states)|(states.*united)` would encapsulate it into one big ugly regex.  Better would just be to split into two clauses (`name LIKE '%united% OR name LIKE '%states%'`)

Comment: its not exactly about united states and countries..It is about any name. as its a autocomplete field and it searches for everything in the entire database(say like thousnd thousands of records in future)..user may enter any name or part of names..whatever phrase matches with any record it should fetch it and i am restricted to use only regularexpression :(

Comment: So tokenize/split the input into the chunks you want to search, and create a where clause for each chunk you split out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23158/discussion-between-developer-and-femtorgon)

Answer (score 5):

Try with `REGEXP` instead of `REGEX`... `;)`

Comment: @Developer What isn't working? You still got your syntax exception, or you got no result but the query is *syntaxically* working?

Comment: this is the error im getting with REGEX                             #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REGEX '^ro$' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1                                         and REGEXP is loading but not getting any values..its still loading

Comment: @Developer then you didn't use `REGEXP` instead of `REGEX`. This error message cannot appear if you follow this answer correctly.

Comment: @Developer Firstly, **do not use `REGEX` anymore**, since it is not the [MySQL keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) you're looking for. Secondly, are you sure it's still loading? How many entries do you have in your `country` table?

Comment: ok sp00m..its still loading..and  i tried with ^ab$ and whole my table has 2000 records.. im working in local

Comment: @Developer try reloading the page. This might be a network issue.

Comment: @Developer I just tried on a table that has about 4500 records, it took 0.0085 sec... What MySQL client are you using? PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: im using mamp..mysql5.0 i guess